# How to display the linebreak in jTemplate

Tags: jquery, json, jtemplates

I am using `jTemplates 0.7.8` to populate data into a template htm file.

The only problem is my json data contains some html tags. Say,

```
{'address':'123 Peter St. <br />city, state, zip', ...}
```

In the template `{$T.record.Address}` does not render 
 as a line break but instead output the literal.

What can we do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found the solution:

Change

```
$('#Container').setTemplateURL("/Templates/MyTemplate.htm");
```

into:

```
$('#Container').setTemplateURL("/Templates/MyTemplate.htm", null, { filter_data: false });
```

Comment: Wonderful solution, you gave me at right time.. thanks.. I wish I could put more upvotes..:)